# Drill REST API and long running queries that exceed the webserver's timeout?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-drill

I'm reading through the Drill REST documentation [here](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rest-api/#query), and they use the following example:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"queryType":"SQL", "query": "select id, sales from dfs.`/Users/joe-user/apache-drill-1.4.0/sample-data/donuts.json` where name= \u0027Cake\u0027"}' http://localhost:8047/query.json
```

The response to this is:

```
{
   "columns" : [ "id", "sales" ],
   "rows" : [ {
     "id" : "0001",
     "sales" : "35",

   } ]
 }
```

But what happens if the query takes longer than the timeout period set from the server?

Is it possible to request an identifier for the query, and then use the id to poll the server for the results? Or is there some other way to handle long running queries for Drill's REST API?

[Further on](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rest-api/#profiles) the docs mention that you can obtain the "profile" of a query given a query id. However, it doesn't mention how to get the results of the query given a query id.